# Can't get utouch to show available wifi networks

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have ubuntu touch installed on a 2014 Nexus 7.

Swiping down from the wireless symbol reveals a "Network" menu with the choices Flight Mode, Wifi Settings, and Cellular Settings.  Wifi Settings leads to another menu: Previous Networks, and Other Networks. Previous Networks shows a list of networks used in the past; Other Networks opens an empty box for typing in the name of a network. I don't see any way to show a list of available networks detected by the device.

On rare occasions, swiping down the wireless symbol actually does bring up a list of detected networks.  But most of the time ubuntu touch exhibits the behavior described above, with no apparent way to bring up the list of available wireless networks.
I would like to see a list of the availble networks, if there is a way to do so.

Edit:  The wifi menu works properly now. Just needed a couple of reboots, it seems.

I have other problems, though. If these other problems persist I will make a post specific to them.

This device is a 2013 Nexus 7 4G. Not sure how to find the ubuntu version. Can't navigate the settings menu right now because it got stuck and there's no way to go back, except to reboot(!)
I'll open multirom manager or boot into recovery and look for the information there.

Comment: Please clarify: **Nexus 7 (gen 1)** or **Nexus 7 (gen 2, 2013)**. Also, what version / build of **Ubuntu Touch** are you running?